# How to dynamically change the chart from shiny app in R?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data.frame which contains 4 columns with 7 rows. Below is the sample data (column name is in uppercase and data is in lower case).

Sample data:

```
NAME.  COUNT  MONTH COUNTRY
ram       20. jan   India
ranjith   40.  jan   India
azhar     80.  feb   India
chris     20   feb   US
rakesh    60.  jan   US
mano.     90.  mar.   UK
Ron.       37.  mar.  uk
```

So in `ui.R` I have created two `selectinputs`. One is with COUNTRY column and other is with MONTH column.

When I select the first `selectinput` as India and second selectinput as jan first two rows should be displayed in shiny app 
as name in x axis(ie horizontally)and COUNT in y axis(ie vertically) with bar chart.

And if I select India in first selectinput and then Feb in second selectinput. Now only the third row need to be appeared with the x axis and y axis mentioned. Meanwhile the results need to be produced for other rows too.

If `COUNTRY` is selected as `UK` and `MONTH` is selected as `jan`, then chart should not get created. Because we don't have record with UK and Jan combination.

Can anyone share the code of `ui.R` and `server.R`?

Comment: I wonder what you have tried because this is fairly straight forward. Take a look at `renderTable` or `renderDataTable` and use normal filter function in the `server.R` to select data to be shown in `ui.R`.

Comment: Psidom..i am new to R programming..can u plz share code of ui.R,server.R if possible

Comment: Can you paste your `ui.R` and `server.R` that you have tried?

Comment: library(shiny)

shinyServer(
  function(input, output){


    CHART_IP_JOB_FAILURE_TEMP <- subset(final1, COUNTRY== input$COUNTRY, COUNT > 0)
    CHART_IP_JOB_FAILURE <- subset(CHART_IP_JOB_FAILURE_TEMP, MONTH== input$MONTH, COUNT > 0)

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      H <- CHART_IP_JOB_FAILURE[,COUNT]
      M <- CHART_IP_JOB_FAILURE[,NAME]

      barplot(H,names.arg = M,xlab = "NAMES",ylab = "COUNT",col = "blue",
              main = "TOP 5 JOB FAILURES",border = "red")

    })

  }
)
 This is my server.R

Comment: require(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage
  (
  titlePanel("sample data"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("COUNTRY",
                  "select country",
                  choices=c("India"= 1,"US" =2,Uk=3),selected ="India"),
      radioButtons("MONTH","select MONTH", choices=c("Jan" = 1,"feb" =2 )),
      mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
    )
  )
)
 This is my ui.R . Plz help me to correct the code

Comment: final1 in server.R is the data.frame in my question..let me know if it helps..

Comment: Yes correct. NAME to be on x axis and COUNT to be on Y axis..if change is done for COUNTRY and MONTH, then chart should change accordingly

Comment: Check the answer, you need to use the `reactive` function to capture the values from input dynamically and use `country()` for example to get the input value.

Comment: (Please edit the code you've added to your comments into your question, using formatted blocks, and delete them from comments. Thanks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you have, you have been very close to what you want. Just need the `reactive` function to dynamically capture the value from the inputs and render output correspondingly:

**ui.R**

```
require(shiny) 
shinyUI(fluidPage( 
    titlePanel("sample data"), 
    sidebarPanel( 
        selectInput("COUNTRY", "select country", choices=c("India","US", "UK"), selected ="India"), 
        radioButtons("MONTH","select MONTH", choices=c("jan","feb"))
        ), 
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot")) 
    ) 
    )
```

**server.R**

```
function(input, output){ 
    country = reactive({input$COUNTRY})          # <<<<<<<<<<< 
    month = reactive({input$MONTH})              # <<<<<<<<<<< 

    output$plot <- renderPlot({ 
        CHART_IP_JOB_FAILURE <- subset(final1, COUNTRY == country() & MONTH == month() & COUNT > 0)
        H <- CHART_IP_JOB_FAILURE[,"COUNT"] 
        M <- CHART_IP_JOB_FAILURE[,"NAME"] 
        barplot(as.numeric(H),names.arg = M,xlab = "NAMES",ylab = "COUNT",col = "blue", main = "TOP 5 JOB FAILURES",border = "red") 
    }) 
}
```

As a resource, the [shiny cheat sheet](http://shiny.rstudio.com/images/shiny-cheatsheet.pdf) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot psidom..wll implement your solution and let u know the details

Comment: Warning in validateSelected(selected, choices, inputId) :
  'selected' must be the values instead of names of 'choices' for the input 'COUNTRY'
Warning in min(w.l) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(w.r) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning: Error in plot.window: need finite 'xlim' values
Stack trace (innermost first):
    79: plot.window
    78: barplot.default

Comment: Psidom..the code which you suggested throws the above error.can u plz suggest me how to proceed..there is no N/A values in my ip dataframe

Comment: And in plot i can able to see the select input values like country and month. Where as it also shows error need finite 'xlimv values. Can u plz explain me how to resolve this